# Stylize Codeigniter Helper Forms with Boostrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I've made a search form on my website using the Codeigniter form helper, but as I'm using Bootstrap for the entire website I want to stylize the form (input, and button) using it.

This is the code for the search function:

```
<?php echo form_open('search/cauta');
      echo form_input('element'); 
      echo form_submit('search_submit', 'Search'); 
      echo form_close(); 
?>
```

How can I make it look like a standard Bootstrap search? I'm passing 'element' to my search/cauta function in my Controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

`form_input(array('name'=>'element', 'class'='yourClassName'));`
you can pass other parameters the same way